# Probability of getting exactly 7 heads in a row, if we flip the coin 10 times

Tags: probability

I know there are 4 ways this can happen

HHHHHHHT(H/T)(H/T) (the last two can be head or tail)

THHHHHHHT(T/H) (the last can be head or tail)

(T/H)THHHHHHHT

(T/H)(T/H)THHHHHHH

**I AM STUCK HOW TO I FIND THE FAVORABLE HERE.**

Comment: What do you mean with "favorable"? Btw, to find the probability just count the number of sequences with exactly $7$ heads in a row and divide by the total number of sequences. This works because all sequences are equiprobable here (if the coin is fair).

Comment: Your second line makes it clear that there are more than 4 ways this can happen, each is a distinct case. Could you write them all up?

Comment: Just start with the first pattern.  Might be easier to write it as $H^7TXX$ where $X$ can be either $H$ or $T$.  How many sequences are there of that form?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your list you divided the favorable casis in four groups, now you just have to count how many casis each group.
Take as an example the first one: the last two tosses of the coin can be either head or tail, so you count  $2\cdot 2=4 $ possible outcome, where the first "2" signifies the possible outcome of the seventh coin, while the other takes in account the possible outcome of the sixth.

If you apply this reasoning to each of the "group of casis" you listed you can calculate the total number of favorable outcome, which amount to $4+2+2+4=12$

Comment: Perfect makes sense thank you

Answer (score 1):

You've defined all of the disjoint cases, so count them up:

- $HHHHHHHT(H/T)(H/T)$ - $4$ outcomes
- $THHHHHHHT(T/H)$ - $2$ outcomes

And so forth. Can you take it from here?